# Windows Azure Deployment Change

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, azure

I created a program and deployed it into the Windows Azure Portal but now I want to change the account that it is associated with but it won't let me. Is this possible and if it is could someone point out how to do it because I can't find a way so far. I created a web service that held data that is consumed by a client and I want to change the associated Windows Azure Account but it keeps trying to publish the service onto the account I used to begin with instead of the new one, even when I sign into my new windows azure account. Using VS to publish the service to the portal

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe your problem - What kind of program you created? What do you mean by `now I want to change the account that it is associated with but it won't let me`?

Comment: I created a web service that held data that is consumed by a client and I want to change the associated Windows Azure Account but it keeps trying to publish the service onto the account I used to begin with instead of the new one, even when I sign into my new windows azure account.

Comment: @GauravMantri meant to tag you.

Comment: Are you publishing it via Visual Studio or via Portal?

Comment: @GauravMantri I am using visual studio to publish it.

Comment: On the publish wizard, have you made sure that you have selected the correct subscription? Another thing you may want to do is sign out in Visual Studio (click on Subscriptions dropdown and then choose last option .... Manage) and sign in again.

Comment: @user3283291 Please *edit your question* with more details, rather than burying them in comments.

Comment: @GauravMantri Hi, thank you. I managed to get to work. It involved a couple of login/log offs but it worked. Thanks!